# Teamcity deploy to Heroku

Tags: ruby, deployment, ssh, heroku, teamcity

I am trying to deploy an app from git on teamcity to Heroku but I keep getting this:

```
Step 2/2: Deploy to Heroku (Command Line)
[22:48:15]: [Step 2/2] Starting: git push git@heroku.com:HEROKUPROJECTNAME.git master
[22:48:15]: [Step 2/2] in directory: /home/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c5d161aeb8cf26ed
[22:48:16]: [Step 2/2] Host key verification failed.
[22:48:16]: [Step 2/2] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
[22:48:16]: [Step 2/2] Process exited with code 128
[22:48:16]: [Step 2/2] Step Deploy to Heroku (Command Line) failed
```

I do have the keys set up. The public key is set up at heroku. This is what my ssh config file looks like:

```
# Heroku forproject
Host heroku.com
HostName heroku.com
User teamcity
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile /home/teamcity/.ssh/teamcity_project_rsa
```

Do you guys have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to push to heroku from build agent manually?

Comment: I mean run command "git push git@heroku.com:HEROKUPROJECTNAME.git master" from command line, not from build script, so we can understand if it is TeamCity fault or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to perform a push from an unauthenticated local host.

Check it with:

```
heroku keys
```

You should grant your public key from the heroku console (given that you are the admin for HEROKUPROJECTNAME) by typing:

```
heroku keys:add
```

Have a look also here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: I actually did that. I added my key in. Funny thing is that it worked from terminal. I even deployed the folder teamcity was trying to push and it worked from terminal. Just teamcity is failing to deploy to heroku.

Comment: Is it possible that in terminal you did use a different user from the user who runs TeamCity build agent?

Comment: and is it OK that you use user git in the url to push and user teamcity in the ssh config?

Comment: So it works from the terminal and I tried to change the user in TeamCity to be "teamcity" instead of "git" and I still get the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure about you doubt.
Let's say that git does not care about local host user identity: what it does worth is that your ssh public key is granted on the remote repo you are trying to push in.
It might be that the process started by teamcity act as another user (and since with different ssh credentials) from the one you use on terminal, try to check it...